# Ubuntu OpenLDAP: TLS init def ctx failed: -1

Tags: openldap

I had a working OpenLDAP but broke it while trying to configure SSL using the instructions here: https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/C/openldap-server.html. Now I'm getting the following error when I try to start ldap with -d -1:

TLS: only one of certfile and keyfile specified

> main: TLS init def ctx failed: -1

Being a newbie, I think it's entirely possible that I messed something up (I have a concern that I did the ldapmodify step from the instructions above wrong), but I don't know how to undo what I've done. I can't start ldapmodify b/c the server is down. So I have two questions:

1. What could be causing this error?
2. How can I get back to my previously working (but no SSL) version of OpenLDAP?

Note: I am not a *nix admin and was only trying to get an SSL version of OpenLDAP to test my app against. So please talk slowly and use big words!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't have access to my openldap server right now, but I'm pretty sure you can change this directly in the fancy new slapd.d/ directory, even though it is not recommended.

See what you get when you run (assuming this is the directory containing your slapd configuration) this:

```
grep -R olcTLS /etc/openldap/slapd.d
```

Comment: That did it! I was able to see that I was missing one of the required config options. I added the olcTLSCertificateKeyFile and was able to get past that error.

Comment: On newest versions of Ubuntu, like Precise, the correct command is grep -R olcTLS /etc/ldap/slapd.d/

Answer (score 1):

According to the [above](https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/C/openldap-server.html) instructions:

> If you run into troubles with the server not starting, check the
>   `/var/log/syslog`. If you see errors like `main: TLS init def ctx failed:
>   -1`, it is likely there is a configuration problem. Check that the certificate is signed by the authority from in the files configured,
>   and that the ssl-cert group has read permissions on the private key.

Comment: `sudo chmod g+r /etc/ssl/private/mykey.key`, saved my day.

Answer (score 0):

Ran into the same error myself, used @fluffywhite's answer, `grep -R /etc/openldap/slapd.d` and found the ldap server was using a different CA file, and the CA in that file had expired.

`olcTLSCACertificateFile` had the path to the CA file slapd was using.

Replaced the CA file with the correct cacert.pem, and slapd started successfully.